# Silverlight: Creating object from subclass of UserControl fails

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inheritance

I have a custom control CustomStackPanel which is a subclass of the StackPanel containing a CheckBox. The XAML is

```
<StackPanel x:Class="MyApp.CustomStackPanel"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="True">check me</CheckBox>
</StackPanel>
```

and the code behind doesn't do much:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class CustomStackPanel: StackPanel
    {
        public CustomStackPanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); // added by Visual Studio
        }
    }
}
```

I can add the CustomStackPanel to the MainPage via XAML like

```
<local:CustomStackPanel />
```

and a CheckBox appears when I run the program. If instead I try to create a panel dynamically and add it to a container the CheckBox does not appear on the screen.

Old code:

```
...
StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
sp.Add(new CheckBox());
somewhere.Add(sp);
...
```

--> I see a checkbox

New code:

```
...
somewhere.Add(new CustomStackPanel());
...
```

--> No checkbox

Comment: I don't see any reason why that wouldn't work. Perhaps the better question is why you are directly manipulating the visual tree in code. You normally don't do that in WPF.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I Also don't see the reason, but I do not see the CheckBox either. I need to add custom controls on runtime.

Comment: But should those controls be in the template of an `ItemsControl`? I suspect there is a better way here.